# remove directory after main url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

With the following url http://www.example.com/de/here/ I want to remove the "de" directory (or whatever may be in front of the "here" directory, if anything even is in front of it) so a user is directed to http://www.example.com/here/ instead, which is a directory that does actually exist.

The url could even be something like http://www.example.com/it/here/ or any other combination of 2 letters.

The url could also just be http://www.example.com/here/ in which case I don't want anything removed at all.

I have searched for a solution here but cant seem to make anything work correctly so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this kind of htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z]{2}/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Example of redirections caused by this code :

```
http://www.example.com/de/foo/  => http://www.example.com/foo/
http://www.example.com/de/      => http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/it/bar/  => http://www.example.com/bar/
http://www.example.com/FR/baz/  => http://www.example.com/baz/
```

Please note you won't be able to access the language (de, it, fr...) anymore.

Another point, be careful with this kind of url (the redirection will be executed twice) :

```
http://www.example.com/de/go/   => http://www.example.com/go/
http://www.example.com/go/      => http://www.example.com/
```

**EDIT**

Now I've got  more details, here is an htaccess you can you to remove the language for specified folders :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z]{2}/here/(.*)$          here/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z]{2}/anotherfolder/(.*)$ anotherfolder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, the problem with this is that like you said, it removes the language dir for everything whereas I only need it to remove the language dir when a particular directory is accessed, which in the example above is "here". So unfortunately this will not work for me.

Comment: You should have mentioned this point from the start, see my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion... anyway your answer works for me now. Thank you so much zessx

Comment: You're welcome. Try to always think about each kind of exceptions when you're using regex, visual schemes can help you.

Comment: Ok will do, thanks for the suggestion. I've been doing a bit of reading on the subject over the past few nights. It was confusing to start with but now I am starting to get a grip on it. Cheers again for the help.