# Local PHP Server Cant See Pages?

Tags: php

So I have my local php server setup and index.php loads fine but I have a folder on my server called pages where, for example, contact.php lives which index.php links to. Shouldn't it just work?

When I try to go to contact.php it just gives me a 404 error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /contact.php was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: The server's looking for `/contact.php`, which would be in your site's document root. if it's in a subfoldder, you have to include that subfolder, e.g. `/pages/contact.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must go to `pages/contact.php` not `contact.php`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/contact.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The code above in your htaccess file will remove the "Pages" directory from your URL's, at which point you can access `/contact.php`

Code above not tested, but you will get the idea.

Comment: See: [Remove Directory from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378326/remove-directory-after-main-url-using-htaccess)  If this helped, mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load `pages/contact.php`, you must type it in the URL (`/pages/contact.php`).

If you want to put `/contact.php` in the URL, configure an `.htaccess` for your web site ( you may check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess, for knowledge, 
and  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/, for learning), or put the `contact.php` in the same level or directory as `index.php`.